# google charts as a javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, function, loops

forgive my javascript.. I want to take the google charts code and use it once as a function then call it in the page loop with a single line as follows:

javascript function (in header)

```
  var taxes, purchase_costs, closing_costs, holding_costs, cost_money, commissions, theid;

 function costPieChart(taxes,purchase_costs,closing_costs,holding_costs,cost_money,commissions,theid)
 {

  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Item');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Cost');
    data.addRows([   
      ['Taxes', taxes],
      ['Purchase Costs', purchase_costs],
      ['Closing Costs', closing_costs],
      ['Holding Costs', holding_costs],
      ['Cost of Money', cost_money],
      ['Commissions', commissions]  
    ]);

    var options = {
    width: 190, legend: 'none',
      colors:['red','blue', '993399', 'grey', 'ff6600', 'green']
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(theid));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
  }
```

then in the html by php loop

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        costPieChart(<?php echo round($method['tax_amount_for_days']).', '.round($method['closing_costs_purchase']).', '.
              round($method['holding_costs']).', '.round($method['cost_of_money']).', '.round($method['commissions_amount']).", 'chart_div".$i."'" ; ?>); 

    </script>
      <div class="chart_wrap"> <div id="chart_div<? echo $i ?>"></div> </div>
```

The loop works renders the javascript and html but alas, the cute lil pie chart is absent. Help?

Answer (score 2):

You never call your `drawChart` function.  You need to call that at some point to draw your pie chart.

```
var options = {
width: 190, legend: 'none',
  colors:['red','blue', '993399', 'grey', 'ff6600', 'green']
};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(theid));
chart.draw(data, options);

drawChart();  // <---  like this
```

}

Comment: doesn't work. And it wasn't ever visibly called in googles chart script. Maybe google calls it on their end.

Comment: @Robert - I'm really not sure.  But to get that pie chart to draw, you'll definitely need to call that function.  As to why it happens to be broken, I'm not sure. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Here we go, _Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value chart_div1 does not match type number in column index 1_
and it repeats for each instance.

Comment: @Robert - I'm not really an expert on google charts.  I would ask a new question detailing the error with your new code.  Also, make sure you tag it with google charts.

Comment: it works. I feel a bit silly. I missed one variable in the call costPieChart line. so it gave the mismatch. Otherwise the code I posted above works fine. Thanks @Adam.